# Rails 4.0 every 3 each div loops then applying class

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have looping here below

```
- @published_only.each do |p|
  .movie.effect
    = image_tag(p.poster_url(:thumb), class: "img")
    .mini-desc
      %h4= p.title
```

it will give

```
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
```

How to make it going to apply 'last' class for every 3 div. for example:

```
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect last>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect>...</div>
<div class="movie effect last>...</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`cycle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-cycle) method:

```
.movie.effect{class: cycle('', '', 'last')}
```